# Why does my Python code ppadb not connect to Memu? From cmd line can adb to Memu. Bluestacks adb python code works but not Memu

Tags: python, android, shell, bluestacks

I have Memu and Bluestacks running on my computer. I am fully interacting with adb on bluestacks. But I am unable to connect to Memu with my python code using ppadb.

If I use the windows and command line "adb -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell" I can access Memu
and same for Bluestacks using "adb -s emulator-5554 shell"

Using this Python code and I can connect to Blue Stacks and interact (eg screencap)

```
import ppadb
from ppadb.client import Client

adb = Client(host='127.0.0.1', port=5037)
#adb = Client()
print(adb.version())
print("getting list of devices")
devices = adb.devices()
for onedevice in devices:
    print(str(onedevice))
print("connecting to Memu")
device = adb.device("emulator-5554")
print("connected")
```

I using the following windows command line command to connect to Memu "adb connect 127.0.0.1:21503"

output from "adb devices -l" is the following

```
C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu>adb devices -l
List of devices attached
emulator-5554          device product:OnePlus5 model:ONEPLUS_A5000 device:OnePlus5
127.0.0.1:21503        device product:A5010 model:A5010 device:A5010
```

I am using the following python code to try to connect to Memu and it just hangs.....

```
import ppadb
from ppadb.client import Client

adb = Client(host='127.0.0.1', port=21503)
#adb = Client()
print(adb.version())
print("getting list of devices")
devices = adb.devices()
for onedevice in devices:
    print(str(onedevice))
print("connecting to Memu")
device = adb.device("127.0.0.1:21503")
print("connected")
```

One would think that If I can interact with the shell of Memu then I should be able to connect via Python.

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to adb server not to the device

```
adb = Client(host='127.0.0.1', port=5037)
```